# Unable to set password for the MySQL "root" user, start: Job failed to start

Tags: server, software-installation, mysql

```
     ┌───────────────────────Configuring mysql-server-5.5─────────────────────────┐
     │ Unable to set password for the MySQL "root" user                           │
     │                                                                            │
     │ An error occurred while setting the password for the MySQL                 │
     │ administrative user. This may have happened because the account already    │
     │ has a password, or because of a communication problem with the MySQL       │
     │ server.                                                                    │
     │                                                                            │ 
     │ You should check the account's password after the package installation.    │
     │                                                                            │ 
     │ Please read the /usr/share/doc/mysql-server-5.5/README.Debian file for     │ 
     │ more information.                                                          │ 
     │                                                                            │
     │                                                                            │
     ├────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤ 
                                      │ < OK > │ 
     └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
start: Job failed to start 
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed. 
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured 
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ... 
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ... 
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.5
 mysql-server 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I issued `ps -e | grep mysqld` after this but got no output.

I have tried everything below but the problem remains:

```
dpkg -S etc/mysql
aptitude purge mysql-server --purge-unused
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update
```

I tried this as well with no luck:

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-client-5.5 mysql-server-5.5 
sudo dpkg -i mysql-5.6.13-debian6.0-i686.deb 
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: I have the same problem.  Upgraded from 14.04.3 to 14.10 with no prob (mysql continuing to work fine).  But the upgrade from 14.10 to 15.04 fails with this error at 75% point - installation just freezes.  It asked for MySQL root password during install, and I entered the current/14.04 password.  But it failed and stopped...

Comment: here my suggestion is to complete remove `mysql`  using `dpkg` with purge option then trying to install again.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to see in what configuration your system really is, with all commands that you tried.  Did you read the `/usr/share/doc/mysql-server-5.5/README.Debian` as suggested in the first part?

Anyway, I would try:
`sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql`

This will give you a chance to enter a root password for MySQL (not to be confused with linux `root`user.

If successful, to start MySQL:
`sudo service mysql start`